# Create custom shape background image on Menu hover using css and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Navigation Menu

I have navigation menu and want to add image on active and hover like this screenshot,and it should set properly if menu text is long or short.

My HTML makup is as given below, i have used images to acheive the custom shape when the link is active, but i dono how to acheive this for hover. Please help.

```
ul#navigation li {
float: left;
list-style: none outside none;
}
ul li a  {
color: #000000; 
text-decoration: none;
}

ul#navigation li.left_bg.starter_active {
    background: url("http://new.nsracing.ch/themes/nsracing/images/btn_left.png")     no-repeat scroll 0 center transparent;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 28px;
    width: auto;
}

ul#navigation li .right_bg.starter_active {
    background:url("http://new.nsracing.ch/themes/nsracing/images/btn_rght.png") no-repeat scroll 100% center transparent;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    padding-right: 23px;
 }

ul#navigation li a.starter_active {
    background: url("http://new.nsracing.ch/themes/nsracing/images/btn_cntr.png")    repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    padding: 9px 0 6px;
}
```

[image]

is there any way to make such shape using any css or jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like a parallelogram

```
ul#navigation li.a:hover{ width: Xpx; height: Ypx; -webkit-transform: skew(zdeg); -moz-transform: skew(zdeg); -o-transform: skew(zdeg); background: yellow; }
```

Comment: thanks sai . The css property skew gives the approximate output. I have used the following markup . ul#navigation li a:hover {
    background-color: #F4DD25;
    border-radius: 13px 0 15px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:8px 19px;
    transform: skewX(-22deg);
}
ul#navigation li a span {
    display: inline-block;
    transform: skewX(10deg);
    -o-transform: skewX(10deg);
    -moz-transform: skewX(10deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(10deg);
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS `Transform` with `border-radius` to achieve what you are looking for.
You can read more about the same below.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform - For Transform
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/border-radius - For border-radius

Hope this helps.